# Calling values from a random row in Parse?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to figure out how to call values from all columns for each variable within a random row, and each row is denoted by its own specific objectId, which is the name of the column, on Parse.  Here is where I've defined the values of the variables in each column:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var voteCount1 = PFObject(className: "VoteCount")
        voteCount1["choices"] = 2
        voteCount1["votes"] = Int()
        voteCount1["votes2"] = Int()
        voteCount1["optionName"] = String()
        voteCount1["optionName2"] = String()
}
```

I've figured out how to make it so that a button will send a vote to a variable's vote count (defined as an Int) in the row of a *specific* object ID, but I don't know how to call polls from a random Object ID and send votes to the corresponding choices in that row.  Here's my IBAction of adding votes to a variable of a specific object ID:

```
@IBAction func addVote1(sender: AnyObject) {
    for button in self.buttons {
        button.enabled = false
    }

    var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("BiEM17uUYT") {
        (voteCount1: PFObject!, error: NSError!) ->Void in
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        } else {
            voteCount1.incrementKey("votes")
            voteCount1.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
        }

        let votes = voteCount1["votes"] as Int
        let votes2 = voteCount1["votes2"] as Int
        let percent1 = votes * 100 / (votes + votes2)
        let percent2 = votes2 * 100 / (votes + votes2)
        self.pollResults1.text = "\(percent1)% (\(votes))                \(percent2)% (\(votes2))"
        }

    }
```

How do I call values from random rows?

UPDATE: I just tried the following re-written from objective-C but I'm not sure if it's right:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: NSArray, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                randNumber = arc4random_uniform(count)
                query2.whereKey("voteNumber", equalTo:randNumber)
                query2.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (voteCount1: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error != nil {
                        NSLog("%@", error)
                    } else {
                        let votes = voteCount1["votes"] as Int
                        let votes2 = voteCount1["votes2"] as Int
                        let option1 = voteCount1["optionName"] as String
                        let option2 = voteCount1["optionName2"] as String
                        self.showOption1.text = "\(option1)"
                        self.showOption2.text = "\(option2)"
            }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean random rows - literally any row in the dataset selected at random?

Comment: That's correct.  I still want to define the corresponding variables as I wrote in the first code above, only retrieved from a random row from the Parse data controller.

Comment: Just retrieve all of the rows into an array and the access a random element

Comment: I've created the array:    var objectId: [String] = ["TtKGatVCi9", "BiEM17uUYT"]  But I'm not sure how to call the values for all the variables from a random row denoted by a certain objectId.  How would I do that?

Comment: You shouldn't hard code the values. You should issue a query against the Parse backend to retrieve the values in your table. You can use the function `arc4random_uniform()` to generate a random number

Comment: Ok, I'm really lost as to how to write a query against my Parse backend unless it's for a specific objectId. Where do I put the arc4random_uniform() ?

Comment: Have you worked through any of the Parse tutorials? You can query for all objects and get back an array. You would never hard code an object id in your code.

Comment: I have. When I use the query getObjectInBackgroundWithId() I have to specify a particular objectId, I can't just call the entire column of objectIds in the parenthesis.  Apparently Parse does not support random queries so I need to find a way around it.

Comment: See my answer - just retrieve all of the values from Parse into memory and then select a random entry.

Answer (score 0):

You would never hard-code object ids in your code.  In order to fetch a random row, simply fetch all of the rows from Parse and then select one at random.

For example

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"VoteCount"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
    NSInteger index=arc4random_uniform(objects.count);
    NSLog("The random object is %@",objects[index]);
  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  }
}];
```

For a more useful implementation you would probably store the `objects` array into a property so that you could refer to it from outside the block.

Note that by default, only the first 100 rows will be returned.  You can increase the limit up to 1000. Beyond 1000 you have to use paging with multiple queries.  See https://parse.com/questions/fetch-all-data-in-a-table-using-pfquery

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: NSArray, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let randomObject=objects[arc4random_uniform(objects.count)] {
                 println("The random object is \(randomObject)\")
             }
        } else {
             println("error \(error)")
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you happen to know how to write that in Swift? I'm having some trouble converting it. I updated my original post with what I have so far but I'm not sure if it's right.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve with your code snippet.  Why are you issuing another query (which isn't initialised correctly by the way)?.  I have updated my answer with the equivalent code in Swift

Comment: I changed the query because the query I had when I incorporated in your code had an error that said "'PFQuery' does not have a member named 'getObjectInBackgroudWithBlock'".  However, when I try the query that you use, "findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock" I get an error that says '[AnyObject]!' is not a subtype of 'NSArray'.  I'm not sure if either of them are the proper queries to use.

Comment: Which line gives the message about [AnyObject]! not being an NSArray?

Comment: The line that says, "query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { "
It actually says [AnyObject]! is not a subtype of 'Int'.

Comment: Ok.  I don't do much with Swift.  I don't find it worth the hassle :).  When I get some time I will see if I can set up a Swift/Parse project and work out what is wrong with the code

Comment: @ansariha Try this: let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(results!.count))